# What is the Last Command referring to?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

I have always wondered, what is the title of the Star Wars Thraw Trilogy novel *Last Command* referring to? Is it Mara's last order from the late Emperor to kill Luke? Or is it in reference to Thrawn being the last of the Grand Admirals, or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is directly addressed in [Star Wars: The Last Command](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Last_Command). Mara Jade is commanded, by the Emperor, telepathically, to ***kill Luke Skywalker***.

The instruction consumes her until she's able to kill Luke('s clone).

> **YOU WILL KILL LUKE SKYWALKER.**
>
> She ducked beneath the slashing blade, gazing into his face. Skywalker’s face. The face that had haunted her nightmares for nearly six years. The face the Emperor had ordered her to destroy.
>
> YOU WILL KILL LUKE SKYWALKER.
>
> And for the first time since she’d found Skywalker and his crippled X-wing floating in deep space, she let herself give in to the voice swirling through her mind. With all her strength, she swung her lightsaber and cut him down.
>
> The clone crumpled, his lightsaber clattering to the floor beside him.
>
> Mara gazed down at him … and as she took a ragged breath, the voice in the back of her mind fell silent.
>
> It was done. She had fulfilled **the Emperor’s last command.**

Answer (score 5):

Throughout the Zahn trilogy, we see [Mara Jade](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Mara_Jade_Skywalker) haunted by her former master, Emperor Palpatine, who, through the Force, had given her one final command when he died:

> You will kill Luke Skywalker

In the course of the novel we learn

> [Joruus C'baoth](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Joruus_C%27baoth) had cloned Luke from the hand he lost in Bespin. In the final confrontation, C'baoth releases the cloned Luke to fight against Jade. Her orders were to kill Luke Skywalker. She kills his clone, and thus fulfills the Emperor's last command.